# Average gpa doesn't match the sum of the student's GPA and don't know how to limit my decimals in my answers

Tags: java

I need to create graphical components with panels. I was able to do this just fine but I'm running across an issue in which the average gpa of my students doesn't match the sum of their gpas/4. I also don't know how to limit my answer to 2 decimal spaces. Any advice would help. Here is my code.

```
public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MainFrame mFrame = new MainFrame();
        
    }
    
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    
    public MainFrame ()
    {
        super ("My First Frame");
        ControlPanel cPanel = new ControlPanel();
        getContentPane().add(cPanel, "Center");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize (640, 480);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ControlPanel extends JPanel{
    
    public ControlPanel ()
    {
        super ();
        BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(border);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        student st1 = new student("Maria", "Gomes");
        student st2 = new student("James", "Michael");
        student st3 = new student("Elena", "Garcia");
        student st4 = new student("Bob", "Jones");
        
        group g1 = new group("Bear", st1, st2, st3, st4);
        TopPanel top = new TopPanel(g1);
        CenterPanel center = new CenterPanel(g1);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(top,"North");
        add(center,"Center");
    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TopPanel extends JPanel {
    
    public TopPanel (group g1)
    {
        super ();
        BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Group Name: " + g1.gName);
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Group Average GPA is" );
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("GPA: " + g1.averageGPA());
        add(jb1);
        add(jb2);
        add(jb3);
        
    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
    
    public CenterPanel (group g1)
    {
        super ();
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4,1);
        setLayout(grid);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Name: " + g1.member1.getInfo() + " " + "Semester GPA: " + g1.member1.semesterGPA());
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Name: " + g1.member2.getInfo() + " " + "Semester GPA: " + g1.member2.semesterGPA());
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Name: " + g1.member3.getInfo() + " " + "Semester GPA: " + g1.member3.semesterGPA());
        JButton jb4 = new JButton("Name: " + g1.member4.getInfo() + " " + "Semester GPA: " + g1.member4.semesterGPA());
        add(jb1);
        add(jb2);
        add(jb3);
        add(jb4);
    }
}

public class group {
    String gName;
    student member1;
    student member2;
    student member3;
    student member4;
    
    group (String groupName, student a, student b, student c, student d)
    {
        gName = groupName;
        member1 = a;
        member2 = b;
        member3 = c;
        member4 = d;
    }
    
    double averageGPA()
    {
       double total = member1.gpa + member2.gpa + member3.gpa + member4.gpa;
       return total / 4.0;
 
    }
}

public class student {
    String fName;
    String lName;
    double gpa;
    
    student (String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        fName = firstName;
        lName = lastName;
        gpa = semesterGPA();
    }
    
    String getInfo()
    {
        return fName + " " + lName;
    }
    
    double semesterGPA()
    {
        gpa = ((double)(Math.random() * (4.0 - 0.0)) + 0.0);
        return gpa;

    }
    
}
```

I'm guessing my issue may lay in how I call average gpa in my TopPanel class but I'm not sure.

Comment: I was able to figure out why the group average didn’t match. If someone could show me how to forgot my answer to only 2 decimals. Would it be by using string.format ?

Comment: I amended my answer to include how to display to two decimal places.  How to do that is at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the average GPA, you are using the gpa that you calculated when you first created each student object.  Your problem is that you are not using that same GPA value when displaying each student's GPA, but are rather computing a new random GPA for each student when you call `semesterGPA` on each `student` object to display that student's GPA on the screen.

To fix the problem, you can change the `student` class's constructor to this:

```
student (String firstName, String lastName)
{
    fName = firstName;
    lName = lastName;
    gpa = ((double)(Math.random() * (4.0 - 0.0)) + 0.0);
}
```

and then change the `semesterGPA` method to just return the same value you calculated when you created the `student` object.

```
double semesterGPA()
{
    return gpa;
}
```

If you want to display the semester GPA of each student to two decimal places, you can instead change this method to the following:

```
double semesterGPA() {
    return Math.round(gpa * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

You can change the display of the average GPA to two decimal places by doing the same calculation in your `averageGPA` class:

```
double averageGPA()
{
    double total = member1.gpa + member2.gpa + member3.gpa + member4.gpa;
    return Math.round(total / 4.0 * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

As a side note: you should name your classes (app, group, student) with capital first letters.  This is the standard convention.  Doing this makes it easier for others to understand your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will make sure to remember this format.